# как сделать сложный нумерованный список

Tags: html, list

Есть список

```html
<ol>
    <li>Собаки</li>
1. Собаки
    <li>Кошки</li>
2. Кошки
    <li>Хомяки</li>
3. Хомяки
</ol>
```

как сделать чтобы он отображал например так

```
3.1 Собаки
3.2 Кошки
3.3 Хомяки
```

и так далее

Comment: язык то какой будет?

Comment: И где он есть этот список - в файле, в памяти, а может в БД или на веб-сайте?

Comment: что-то я совсем туплю. В простом HTML

Comment: А не пробовали ещё один уровень вложения тегов li сделать? Я точно не помню, но может так

Answer (score 3):

Если правильно понял, что просто HTML, то так:

```css
li { list-style-type: none; } /* Убираем исходную нумерацию у списка */
   ol { counter-reset: list1+2; } /* Инициируем счетчик */
   ol li:before {
    counter-increment: list1; /* Увеличиваем значение счетчика */
    content: counter(list1) ". "; /* Выводим число */
   }
   ol ol { counter-reset: list2; } /* Инициируем счетчик вложенного списка */
   ol ol li:before {
    counter-increment: list2; /* Увеличиваем значение счетчика вложенного списка */
    content: counter(list1) "." counter(list2) ". "; /* Выводим число */
```

```html
<ol>
   <li>Собаки
    <ol>
     <li>Собака 1</li>
     <li>Собака 2</li>
     <li>Собака 3</li>
    </ol>
   </li>
   <li>Кошки
    <ol>
     <li>Кошка 1</li>
     <li>Кошка 2</li>
    </ol>
   </li>
  </ol>
```